# How to enable Intel Iris Xe GPU for TensorFlow+Keras on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to leverage Intel Iris Xe Graphics to train my models using keras & tensorflow.
I found the script to check if the MKL flag is enabled & my system detects the GPU.
But the script does not detect Intel GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def get_mkl_enabled_flag():

    mkl_enabled = False
    major_version = int(tf.__version__.split(".")[0])
    minor_version = int(tf.__version__.split(".")[1])
    if major_version >= 2:
        if minor_version < 5:
            from tensorflow.python import _pywrap_util_port
        else:
            from tensorflow.python.util import _pywrap_util_port
            onednn_enabled = int(os.environ.get('TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS', '0'))
        mkl_enabled = _pywrap_util_port.IsMklEnabled() or (onednn_enabled == 1)
    else:
        mkl_enabled = tf.pywrap_tensorflow.IsMklEnabled()
    return mkl_enabled

print ("We are using Tensorflow version", tf.__version__)
print("MKL enabled :", get_mkl_enabled_flag())



# Check available physical devices (GPUs)
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

if len(physical_devices) == 0:
    print("No GPU devices found.")
else:
    for device in physical_devices:
        print("GPU:", device)

# Check if Intel GPU is being used
intel_gpu_in_use = False
for device in physical_devices:
    if 'Intel' in tf.config.experimental.get_device_name(device):
        intel_gpu_in_use = True

print("Is Intel GPU being used?", intel_gpu_in_use)
```

This script throws an output that Intel gpu is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

To enable **Intel Iris Xe GPU** support for TensorFlow on Windows, follow these steps:

Install the required versions of TensorFlow and Keras:

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu==2.10
pip install keras==2.10
```

Note: It is essential to install the CPU version of TensorFlow because the directml plugin currently only supports CPU.

Install the TensorFlow DirectML plugin:

```
pip install tensorflow-directml-plugin
```

The TensorFlow DirectML plugin allows TensorFlow to offload computations to DirectML, which can take advantage of the underlying hardware, including the Intel Iris Xe GPU.

For more detailed information and troubleshooting, you can refer to the official Microsoft documentation on GPU acceleration with TensorFlow on Windows using DirectML:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-windows